# Is Create Spatial Type necessary

Tags: postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, installation

When I enable an enterprise geodatabase for a database in postgresql, the st_geometry type get installed with it. So Is it necessary to use "Create Spatial Type" tool to create st_geometry type in postgresql again?

One benefit of this tool is to upgrade existing st_geometry type. But for a fresh install, is it necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **never** necessary to use Create Spatial Type on a properly configured enterprise geodatabase.

Create Spatial Type is a limited *subset* of Enable Enterprise Geodatabase, where only the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY datatype is wanted. Quoting the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000016n000000) (emphasis mine):

> This allows you to use the ST_Geometry SQL type to store geometries
>   **in a database that does not contain a geodatabase**

Your "benefit" is an unsupported use pattern, which might cause corruption of a geodatabase (preventing function when in a hybrid state and/or proper upgrade).  I strongly discourage the use for this purpose.

In fact, I've only had one case where I *needed* to use Enable Enterprise Geodatabase (and that was on Oracle); at all other times I've used Create Enterprise Geodatabase (after creating the database exactly as I wanted it with createdb, createuser, and psql -- the "Create" tool skips unnecessary steps).

Comment: Thanks Vince. I expected an answer from you! Then what is the use case of this tool? e.g. The user only needs st_geometry and no other geodatabase capabilities!

Comment: Yes, only for SDE.ST_Geometry support (which isn't really a geodatabase capability, as evidenced by the lack of ST_Geometry in SQL-Server)